# Can I process existing IP entries on the fly to get geolocation data?

Tags: elasticsearch, geo

I have **existing** indexed IP entries that I now would like to link to geographic data.

I know that I could have done it at ingestion time through the [GeoIP processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geoip-processor.html).

Is there a mechanism in ElasticSeach that would "join" (or "merge") such external data upon a query (in other words, when I query ES for data, the IP data would be augmented with/from an external geo location source, probably a MM GeoLoc2 file).

I guess the alternative would be to either reindex or update the existing entries?

Comment: You can update by query your index by leveraging the same pipeline with GeoIP processor that you would have used at indexing time

Comment: @Val - sorry I am not sure I understand. You mean updating the existing data (via the geoip processor), or leveraging the geoip processor at request time (= without changing the data that is in ES)?

Comment: I mean the former you can update/re-enrich your existing data as if it had been enriched at ingestion time. There's no way to do it at query time... wouldn't make sense either since IP addresses don't move, so their geo location is pretty constant and it's better to compute it once and for all than looking it up on every search query

Comment: @Val, OK - that's clear. As for the movement of IP addresses, they do move very much (including internationally) though ARIN registrations, but the logic would be to capture their location at ingestion time (where it was at the time)

Comment: Agreed, that's also possible that IPs move indeed, but the point I think is to capture a point in time location

Comment: Also worth noting that Opensearch has an RFC going on that pretty much ressembles what you're asking for, but I'm not sure about the maturity: https://github.com/opensearch-project/search-processor/issues/80